# I want to improve my search facility in http://www.go4film.com

Tags: php, mysql

I need help in building custom search engine for my website http://www.go4film.com.

Although my website search works perfectlly in finding movie but the problem is that if I made a search on my website using the search term "State Department File" as there is a movie named 'State Department File' was already in my database then my search engine perfectly working in finding the movie but the problem is that it shows all movies related to the terms like "State","Department",'File' so it results more than 150 movies fom my database so user had to search again from the search result returns from my website.

SO i need a php script which searches my database and returns the result related to each words in my search query but the first result must be same to the search term so that user find the result in the first page no nedd to search among the results

This is the table where i am using for searching in my database

...

And i need only search in my film_name field.

Please help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) you can try playing with:

```
SELECT
    MATCH('column') AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2') as Relevance
FROM
    table
WHERE
    MATCH('column') AGAINST('+keyword1 +keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
HAVING
    Relevance > 0.2
ORDER BY
    Relevance DESC
```

Comment: thanx for your answaer.Its really helpfull for me.